Post-Processing hiding gameObjects in Gameview & in game runntime?
So the problem is that my Post-Processing is hiding my gameObjects, sprites and Ui Elements.
I found out that if you put the Volume weight less than 0.126 than all sprites will appear at the gameview:
1 Image

2 image

But if i put the Volume weight less than 0.126 the Post-Processing stops working.
How to fix this problem???
I have the "Post-Processing Volume" on my camera (Camera is on default layer)
